# JQuery Ajax code not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I hope someone can help me to identify the problem I am having with the following jquery Ajax code. Below php file is calling a Select statement when having choosen the Staff member from the dropdown list. 
In the input list the salary of the staff member should appear. Unfortunately nothing happens.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>AJAX und PHP ganz einfach!</title>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.id').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'anzeige.php',
            data: 'id=' +$('.id').val(),
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#ajaxAusgabe').html(msg);
                }
        });     
    }); 
}); //document.ready


</script>



<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","sandrag","bubblekey13","staffbridgetest");
if (!$link) {

    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


$db_selected = mysql_select_db("staffbridgetest", $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
</head>






  <p>Bitte waehlen Sie einen Mitarbeiter:</p>

     <form>

         <select name="id">
         <option value=""></option>
           <?php


$query = mysql_query("SELECT Mitarbeiternummer, Vorname, Nachname FROM mitarbeiter where mitarbeiternummer>0 order by nachname"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['Mitarbeiternummer'].'">'.$row['Nachname'].', '.$row['Vorname'].'</option>';
}
     echo'</select>';

                        ?>


 <div id="ajaxAusgabe"></div>

   </form> 





</script> 



</body>
</html>
```

This is connected to another php file with the Select statement:

```
 <?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","sandrag","bubblekey13","staffbridgetest");
if (!$link) {

    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


$db_selected = mysql_select_db("staffbridgetest", $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}


$staffid=$_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT Stundenlohn from gehalt where mitarbeiternummer='$staffid' limit 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

 echo $row['Stundenlohn'];
 }




?>
```

I really don't know why it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the console?

Comment: `$('select[name=id]').change(function() {...})`

Comment: Posting both JS **and** PHP shows that you haven't taken the effort to at least localize where to problem is. Please do some debugging, check what the PHP page generates, etcetc..

Comment: The console doesn't give me an errors

Comment: .id is referring to the select name of the drop down menu. I have tried also with #id but no luck

Comment: So, see my previous comment...

Comment: You forgot to add `method="post"` on your form

Comment: `.` refers to a `class` and `#` refers to an `id` - you have neither on your select... so take @roasted 's advice **or** add a `class` or `id` to your `select`.

Comment: Great with the method and change to select id it is now working. One problem is left. I actually want to show the value in an input type="text". But this doesn't work. The value is not getting displayed within the value="" but like this: <input type="text" value="" id="ajaxAusgabe">
9.00
</input>

Comment: Ohh just wanted to point out that you have a closing `</script>` without an opening. And you're also missing the opening body `<body>` tag.

Comment: AjaxAusgabe isn't div? You changed your code I see and remember that id referes to unique element, there can be only 1 element with particular id. To change input you should use `$("#ajaxAusgabe").val('value');` instead of` html()`

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your message. I changed it to $("#ajaxAusgabe").val('value') but this didn't help. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You binding event to element that should have class named "id" but there is no such element

change

```
<select name="id">
```

to

```
 <select name="id" class="id">
```

and it will work.

- `.` is used to reference the class=""
- `#` is used to reference the element with paricular id=""

You can also select element by name with `select[name=id]`.

```
$('select[name=id]').change(function() { //this will find <select> where attribiute name is equal to "id" and bind change event to it.
```

You should read more about [Jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)